# CSS Floating an element next to a PHP echoed element

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a php function that creates a  that includes some information in it and a picture (plain HTML) i want to float the picture left and the echoed php function right.

[IMG] [ blah ]

What currently is happening is the image appears above the echoed function

Here is some of the code:

**PHP Function Declaration:**

```
function create($preTag ,$name , $description , $downloadlink) {
echo "  <div>
        <h3>$preTag $name</h3> <ln>
        <br>
        <h2>$description </h2>
        <br>
        <h2><a href= $downloadlink >Click here to download!</a> </h2>
        </div>
     ";
}
```

**PHP Function Call:**

```
create("Game:" , "Pong Clone", "A small pong clone. Completed: [Feb 21, 2013]" , "https://github.com/Bevilacqua/Pong");
```

**CSS For div:**

```
div {
border-radius: 2em;
background-color: #ffffa6;
border: .3em solid white;
float: right;
display: inline;
}
```

**CSS For img:**

```
img {
float: left;
display: inline;
}
```

**HTML For img: (Just a test Image)**

```
<a href="www.google.com">
<img src="http://www.dsga.org/images/tournament_sign_up_button.gif">
</a>
```

Comment: Your PHP isn't relevant if your question is related to style.  Show the HTML being output from your script.  Also, make sure you use `htmlspecialchars()` around variable data used in the context of HTML.  This will ensure you are generating valid HTML, as well as prevent against XSS attacks, should you be using variable data that can be injected.

Comment: you miss to enclose the url in "a" tag you can use ' <a href='$downloadLink'>...

Comment: Where is the html for the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you image isn't too big.
I tried your code and it works fine with a smaller image. With a big image (width) it will not have enough space to be next to it.

Comment: I tried with a smaller picture still showing up above the other element

Comment: It just works fine for me when I test it.
Where do you use the create function?

Comment: The picture wasnt to large, the php echo is. Is there a way to automatically create a line break without hardcoding it in (<br>) that will keep them the same size every time?

Comment: try echo-ing every single line and try adding  `/n` in front of every echo

Answer (score 0):

I did exactly as Patrick Brouwers and I came to the same answer : Your image is just too big. Here is a Fiddle to show it.
http://jsfiddle.net/kEwan/

```
float:right;
```

and

```
float:left;
```

work fine.
Try to resize the width of the result windows, and you'll see it.

Note : Be careful with you link of the  tag, because it should have double quotes around it.

Comment: I tried with a smaller picture still showing up above the other element

Comment: @Bevilacqua Off-topic but what browser do you use? If Firefox, then grab Firebug and play with the css attributes until you get the output you want. Please if you use IE6 close it now.

Comment: F12 in Chrome opens the Firebug-equivalent.